# Flutter - rootBundle.load not working in web

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm developing a flutter aplication with support mobile and web, and in my assets I keep a sample .pdf to allow the user test the behavior of some features before actually using them. With that purpose I load the pdf as follow:

```dart
  final data = (await rootBundle.load('assets/test.pdf')).buffer.asUint8List();
  print(data);
```

In mobile this works fine but in web it returns an empty array.
How this can be fix? Is needed another approach for the web?

Comment: Can you add `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` in main, before runApp function?